# Unable to update Facebook Payments settings

Tags: facebook-credits

I've been experiencing the popular error "Unable to update Facebook Payments settings" for months now when adding the Callback URL page on the App > Credits dev tab. 
I've tried the following:

- Tried setting app as sandbox and non-sandbox
- The callback page gives back a 200 OK (tried any URL for that matter)
- I added legitimate Company information for the FB Credits account
- Tried with and without adding test users

The error appears whether I edit the Callback URL and/or the test users. Currently both fields are empty as this is a new app (created it March 2011). Other apps I own that have been created in 2010, whether they're active or completely blank config-wise, work perfectly when I go and edit their Credits info, even when bogus information is entered. So this bug is clearly only affecting "new" apps.

My app is ready for production and I only require my FB Credits account to be enabled to start.

Will provide App ID if a dev can look into it. I am a verified developer and have other apps which work (but had added payment information on the old GUI).

Thank you

p.s.: I am aware of the other posting referring to this and I didn't know how to add my voice without being tagged as an "answer" ( [Error - Unable to update Facebook Payments settings](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7260732/error-unable-to-update-facebook-payments-settings) ). Sorry about the cross-posting.

Comment: I have the same exact problem, and cannot find an answer anywhere. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be url dependant. I can set the same, completely random url (http://something.random.invalid/some/path/?some=thing&key=123) for two applications - for one application it is accepted and for the other one it is not. It also doesn't seem to be user dependant as both applications are owned by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

After some frustrating experimentations I was able to determine that the problem can be avoided when the *Credits Callback URL* setting is initialised together with the *Company Country* setting. After initial form submission it can be freely altered.

Unfortunately, the *Company Country* setting can be set only once, so... :) The only working solution seems to be **application recreation** and **proper settings initialisation**. If you have a production application, which can't be recreated, you probably have to find some direct Facebook technical support.

To summarise other discovered "facts":

- The error seems to be URL independent.
- The error seems to be admin user independent.
- The error also seems to be browser/OS independent (tested on rekonq, FF and some IE).